# How to use QMake's subdirs template?

Tags: qt, qmake, subdirectory

I'm starting to learn Qt. I'm moving from the Visual Studio world and I am looking for a way to organize my project's structure using QMake. I've found the 'subdirs' template but I have quite a hard time understanding it.

My project structure looks like this:

```
project_dir/
    main.cpp
    project.pro
    logic/
      logic.pro
      some logic files
    gui/
      gui.pro
      gui files
```

My *project.pro* looks like this

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = logic \
          gui
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

In the *.pro* files for the subdirectories I have appropriate *SOURCES*, *HEADERS* and *RESOURCES* variables set.

Please tell me what *TARGET*, *TEMPLATE* and other necessary values I should set in the *.pro* files.

Also, is there some good QMake tutorial other than the official one?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

In addition to [Troubadour's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417776/how-to-use-qmakes-subdirs-template/1417801#1417801), I would note that the `SUBDIRS` target is only good for specifying subdirectories.  Therefore, your extra line of

```
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

in your project.pro file is incorrect, and will likely fail to build your main.cpp file, at worst.  At best, qmake will refuse to parse the file, since it has conflicting specifications in it.

I've used the `SUBDIRS` template a few times, and it does well if you can build parts into more-or-less independent libraries, apparently like you have with the logic and the gui separate.  Here is one way to do this:

```
project_dir/
-project.pro
-common.pri
-logic/
----logic.pro
----some logic files
-gui/
----gui.pro
----gui files
-build/
----build.pro
----main.cpp
```

project.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = logic \
          gui

# build must be last:
CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS += build
```

common.pri:

```
#Includes common configuration for all subdirectory .pro files.
INCLUDEPATH += . ..
WARNINGS += -Wall

TEMPLATE = lib

# The following keeps the generated files at least somewhat separate 
# from the source files.
UI_DIR = uics
MOC_DIR = mocs
OBJECTS_DIR = objs
```

logic/logic.pro:

```
# Check if the config file exists
! include( ../common.pri ) {
    error( "Couldn't find the common.pri file!" )
}

HEADERS += logic.h
SOURCES += logic.cpp

# By default, TARGET is the same as the directory, so it will make 
# liblogic.a (in linux).  Uncomment to override.
# TARGET = target
```

gui/gui.pro:

```
! include( ../common.pri ) {
    error( "Couldn't find the common.pri file!" )
}

FORMS += gui.ui
HEADERS += gui.h
SOURCES += gui.cpp

# By default, TARGET is the same as the directory, so it will make 
# libgui.a (in linux).  Uncomment to override.
# TARGET = target
```

build/build.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += -L../logic -L../gui -llogic -lgui

# Will build the final executable in the main project directory.
TARGET = ../project
```

Comment: It's my impression that "ordered" is global. It doesn't seem to make the first two libraries concurrently.

Comment: @Walter Nissen: You are correct, so far as I know.  Ordered means they all run consecutively, and in the order specified.  You can actually manually specify dependencies between the subdir targets if you want to, which would possibly allow concurrent builds, but is harder to set up properly.

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot, can you please clarify: "I would note that the SUBDIRS target is only good for specifying subdirectories." You mean you can't use `TEMPLATE = subdirs` and *also* specify `TARGET`, `SOURCES` etc in order to actually build something, in the same .pro?

Comment: Following up from my previous query: As suggested you cant also do a `app` build from the subdirs project file, but you don't actually need to put the qmake for your main executable in a subdir - "build/". You can add the "build.pro" to the end of the `SUBDIRS` list - i.e. have two .pros in the top level.

Comment: @SamPinkus That is correct.  I don't recall if that was supported when I wrote this answer, but in some situations that would be simpler for the final link, over created an entire subdirectory.

Answer (score 18):

You use `subdirs` if the logic and gui folders actually repesent some sort of target, eg. a library, that can be built independently of anything else. If that's the case then just use

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = logic
CONFIG += dll
```

in logic.pro.

If they are not independent targets but are just folders that exist to organise the sources files then you can just use a .pri file in each instead and include them within the .pro using

```
include(logic/logic.pri)
include(gui/gui.pri)
```

Just remember that the file paths in the .pri files are relative to the .pro file and *not* the .pri. BTW, the use of a .pri file is optional as you can still list the files in those folders directly in the .pro file. The .pri file just makes it that bit neater and helps keep the .pro file shorter.

Comment: From what I've learned, the .pri file method causes Qt Creator to display subfolder for each .pri file and its contents.

Comment: @zarzych: That's true but it also annoyingly doesn't respect where the .pri file is in the file system and just displays them as a flat list at the .pro level. Particularly annoying if you have several with the same name.