# Qt dependencies between projects

Tags: qt, dependencies

I have several projects that are load together in QtCreator and they're not grouped under a unique project.
I need to create dependencies between these modules and not only considering TARGETDEPS that checks only if the library is present in a directory.

The dependency I request, practically it must emulate the user action in qtcreator of checking in "Edit project settings" the dependency list ay the bottom of the page.
So if a module depends from other module , qtcreator first qmake/make/etc.. the other one.
How can I do?

thank you
daniele

Answer (score 1):

I never try it myself (because I use Scons for big multi-projects application) but the QMake subdirs target may be what you're looking for:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmake-variable-reference.html#subdirs

There is a fairly detailed explanation of how to use it here : [How to use QMake's subdirs template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417776/how-to-use-qmakes-subdirs-template)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I was just looking for the answer to "how to specify the dependencies between projects in QtCreator?", this post is the first result, and all others either also recommend SUBDIRS project or are not relevant.

**Why I don't want SUBDIRS?**

- I don't want to create another project.
- Because of some legacy my projects are spread around the repository, not organised in a nice tree.
- I have one common library and several projects depending on it. I don't want to have all of them loaded at the same time. I only want the library and one of the projects.

**What I recommend?**

In the left column choose "Projects", then in "Project Settings" choose Dependencies. In the middle area you will see a list of projects. Check those that the current project depends on.

[image: screenshot of QtCreator dependencies page]

My solution can be the same thing as your *checking in "Edit project settings" the dependency list at the bottom of the page* but because of continuing QtCreator development it looks different 10 years later.