# QtCreator: Avoid redefining LIBS in Qt subdirs project

Tags: qt-creator, libs, subdirectory

I have a Qt `subdirs project` with the following structure:

```
ExternalQtProject 
QtSubdirProjects
  - GUI
  - WebService
```

`WebService` contains `LIBS` from the external Qt project (.pro file in WebService)

```
LIBS += -L<path to ExternalQtProject>
LIBS += <some ExternalQtProject .obj files>
```

`GUI` uses the web service (.pro file in GUI):

```
LIBS += -L<path to WebService>
LIBS += <WebService .obj files>
```

So basically `GUI` is using one header file from `WebService`, which in turn uses several header files from `ExternalQtProject`.

Problem: I get linker issues until I include the `LIBS` entries from `WebService` as well in `GUI`, so `GUI` ends up with all LIBS from the `ExternalQtProject`:

```
LIBS += -L<path to ExternalQtProject> # I want to avoid redefinition of this
LIBS += <some ExternalQtProject .obj files>  # I want to avoid redefinition of this
LIBS += -L<path to WebService>
LIBS += <WebService .obj files>
```

Since there is a clear dependency (GUI->WebService->ExternalQtProject), **is there a way to avoid this redefinition** of `LIBS` for the `GUI` sub project?

-- Edit 1 --

[How to use QMake's subdirs template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417776/how-to-use-qmakes-subdirs-template) helps me to better structure my project, but not yet avoiding the duplication of `LIBS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qmake .pro files can use variables and include other files.

You can e.g. use SOMELIST=foo.obj bar.obj and LIBS += $$SOMELIST when needed.

A SUBDIRS template is used to list different .pro files, each typically responsible for building one binary or one library.