# QMake SUBDIRS project: How to call release-clean from top-level Makefile?

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake, nmake

I am using a Qt .pro file using the [SUBDIRS](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html#subdirs) template (mainly following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1417859/808151)).

Furthermore I am building my solution using `qmake -recursive MyProject.pro` and `nmake Release`.

Now I want to supply a separate batch file for cleaning up the release output and meta files (not the debug ones though).

The problem is that for the top-level `Makefile`, only `clean` and `distclean` is generated by `qmake` while for the subdirectories, there are also `release-clean` and `debug-clean` (also the folders contain an additional `Makefile.Debug` and `Makefile.Release`).

What I want to do is calling

```
nmake Makefile release-clean
```

from the batch script. However the top-level makefile does not contain this configuration.

Now I could call the equal line for every subproject manually but this is obviously my least favoured option.

Is there a way to either get qmake to generate a `release-clean` target for the top-level makefile or is there another way to simply clean release files?

PS: I'm using nmake, so yes I'm on Windows (XP) and using MSVC (2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following batch script does the job :

```
REM set up environment
SET VISUALDIR=C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.0
PUSHD %VISUALDIR%\VC
CALL vcvarsall.bat x86
POPD

REM clean solution
msbuild yoursolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /t:clean

REM and you may want to add a build command :
msbuild yoursolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

Comment: This is true if you have a VS Solution, however I'm just using `qmake` on the `.pro` file and then `nmake`. I could maybe add a `qmake -tp vc -recursive xxxx.pro` to generate the sln and then compile it the way you suggested.

Comment: @TimMeyer oh ok. indeed I assumed you were using a visual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ever tried `nmake Makefile.Release clean`, that should do the job.

Comment: You might not have realized, but this post is 9 years old. A lot has changed since then, and I no longer have this problem, so I can't really tell if this would have worked