# Qt cannot open Lib file - LNK1104 Cannot open file 'DbManager.lib'

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QT Creator 2.7.0 based upon QT 5.0.2 on a Windows 7 machine and attempted to create a subdirs project with three sub-projects.

```
Project_Dir
     - DbManager
     - Gui
     - Build
```

Using the example here [How to use qmakes subdirs template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417776/how-to-use-qmakes-subdirs-template), I created the Project files listed below, however, upon building I keep getting the error `LNK1104 Cannot open file 'DbManager.lib'`

My search usually yeilds results for Visual Studio type fixes, but no QT fixes

Project.pro

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += \
    DbManager \
    Gui

CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS += Build
```

DbManager.pro

```
! include( ../common.pri ) {
    error( Couldnt find the common.pri file! )
}

HEADERS += dbmanager.h

SOURCES += dbmanager.cpp
```

Gui.pro

```
! include( ../common.pri ) {
    error( Couldnt find the common.pri file! )
}

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = target
SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Build.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app

DEPENDPATH += ../Gui
INCLUDEPATH += ../Gui

DEPENDPATH += ../DbManager
INCLUDEPATH += ../DbManager
LIBS += -L../DbManager -L../Gui -lDbManager -lGui

SOURCES += main.cpp

TARGET = ../OptionsTrader

QT += widgets
```

The following "Common.pri" file, was also included:

```
INCLUDEPATH += . ..
WARNINGS += -Wall
TEMPLATE = lib
UI_DIR = uics
MOC_DIR = mocs
OBJECTS_DIR = objs
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem before, and I just copy the lib file into the project working directory,it worked.