# qmake subdir template on mac os X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5, qmake

im create subdir template for Qt (5.2.0) project as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417776/how-to-use-qmakes-subdirs-template)

i can build this on win and linux platform with minGW and GCC but on mac os im getting next error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libfile-helpers.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/myusername/Programming/Qt/build-ProjectName-qt-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_clang_64bit-Debug/build/project
Reason: image not found
```

The program has unexpectedly finished.

otool -L on main executable gives next output

```
libfile-helpers.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
libgui.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/Users/myusername/Qt/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
/Users/myusername/Qt/5.2.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.2.0, current version 5.2.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 60.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

but files *.dylib placed in subdirs and cant be found in current setup

how to setup project for proper run after build without manual file manipulations
one change i make in build.pro (see answer in beginning ) is adding next text

```
macx {
   CONFIG -= app_bundle
}
```

(uname -a)

```
Darwin MacBook.local 13.0.2 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.2: Sun Sep 29 19:38:57 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.75.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

with qmake ( -v )

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.0 in /Users/myusername/Qt/5.2.0/clang_64/lib
```

and clang ( -v )

```
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2
Thread model: posix
```

Im nooby in osX native development and cant solve this by myself.
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X deployment process is a bit different then on other platforms. Mostly you will create application bundle that must contain all required libraries with it. Qt documentation describes whole process very well. Here are some resources:

[Qt for Mac OS X - Deployment](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/macosx-deployment.html)

Take a look at [The Mac Deployment Tool](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/macosx-deployment.html#the-mac-deployment-tool)

Comment: But i still can debug project if i run it as bundle?

Comment: If you won't strip it from debugging symbols

Comment: Problem still present. inside bundle presented only executable with links to project libraries like they in same folder with him

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Did you follow all steps in deployment process? Did you change your library install_name? It should be in bundle.app/Contents/Frameworks directory, no links

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have such a subdirs project with this directory structure:

```
subdirs
  + app
  + lib
```

That is, a subdirs project (here, creatively called `subdirs`) with an app (called `app`) and a lib (called `lib`) project.

Now, if your `app` uses the dynamically linked/shared `lib` project within your `subdirs` project on OSX, you will get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libLIBTARGET.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /path/to/qt/build/dir/build-PROJECT-DETAILS/APPDIR/APPTARGET
  Reason: image not found
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

where

- `LIBTARGET` is the `TARGET` value of your `lib` project,
- `PROJECT` is the name of your `subdirs` project,
- `DETAILS` are your build & run details,
- `APPDIR` is the directory of the `app` project, and
- `APPTARGET` is the `TARGET` value of your `app` project.

To get rid of this problem on OSX during the development of the project, you need to set the (OSX-specific) `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the `lib` directory to the entire project's run settings in *Projects -> Build & Run -> Run Environment*
and add the Variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` with Value `../LIBDIR/` - or, if you are working from the command line, `export` that variable.

Then, for deploying the app, you need to make sure the dynamic library is placed within your app bundle or create a statically compiled bundle. More here on [Digia: Mac OSX Deployment](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.2/macosx-deployment.html).