# Qt sub-project undefined reference to `main'

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, mvp

I'm learning The Model-View-Presenter (MVP) Pattern with Qt and have the **[follow example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ifIdidcU5fY09fMDZyOU4zaTA/view?pli=1)**. I can build it and run it from build folder, but can't debug it due to the error:

```
.../glibc-2.19/sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:118: error: undefined reference to `main'
error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't figure out what's wrong? A quick Google search brings not much information.
PS: I use OpenSUSE 13.1 with Qt 4.8

Comment: That's a linker error, which you should get when you build your program, meaning you can't run it. And you *do* have a `main` function in your program?

Comment: Yes, I do have `main()` in sub project `Presenter`. If you use linux you can go to the `deployment` folder and the program can run from there.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Hi, I use QtCreator 2.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `subdirs` template wrong. It should not contain anything, but `SUBDIRS` and sometimes `CONFIG += ordered`. Also your project model is a bit complicated. You should try something simplier first, without libraries and subprojects.

Good example of subdirs project: [How to use QMake's subdirs template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417776/how-to-use-qmakes-subdirs-template)

**Update**

I'll explain a bit. Minimal changes you need to do in your project in order it to compile & link:

1. remove `SOURCES = $$PWD/Presenter/main.cpp` line from `WiringClone.pro`
2. add `CONFIG += ordered` to `WiringClone.pro` and `View.pro`
3. remove `config \` line from `WiringClone.pro` (this is the one that caused the original link error)
4. order subprojects. `WiringClone.pro`: `Utilities Model View Presenter`, `View.pro`: `Logic GUI`

But, even after all these changes you'll have to solve an unsolvable problem: your `Utilities` library depends on your `Model` library, but your `Model` depends on your `Utilities`. Linking doesn't work this way. Cyclical dependencies are not allowed. That's why I recommend you to loose all your libraries and write a simple solid executable first.

Comment: You mean the root project? I add `SOURCES = $$PWD/Presenter/main.cpp` after the linker complains about `undefined reference to `main'`. But it ain't work.

Comment: And I already did a small project similar to this but every code files in the same directory. So I want to take a few step more: re-structure ...

Comment: First step from here is to move files into different directories and add them to project like this: 'SOURCES += src/model/model.cpp src/view/view.cpp' etc. Second step is to learn how to use `pri` files. Third step is to write a subdir, containing only 2 projects - one library and one executable, which uses it. And only after doing all this you sould try somethig as complicated, as your exaple. Yes, life is pain ^_^.

Comment: Thank, it works :D Do you have any suggestion about cyclical dependencies between `Utilities` and `Model`? I think I should merge `Utilities` into methods of `WiringModel`.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely merge something into something else. For example `Utilities` into `Model`.